# How to add custom fields on to Liquid form?

Tags: html, ruby, liquid

I have a possiblity to edit online store pages in Liquid language. The contact pages encoded this way by default:

(this is storenvy.com store)

```
<fieldset>
{% if contact.sent %}
<div id="request_received">
<img src="images/support_received.png" />
<h2>Support request received!</h2> 
<p>Your request was received. We will take care of your issue as soon as possible.<br />Thank you!</p>
</div>
{% else %}
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action ="/contact">
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="label" id="first_label">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field" id="first_field">
      {{ contact | contact_input: 'name'}}
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="label">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      {{ contact | contact_input: 'email'}}
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="label">
      <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      {{ contact | contact_input: 'phone'}}
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="label">
      <label for="order_number">Order Number</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      {{ contact | contact_input: 'order_number'}}
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="label">
      <label for="message">Details</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      {{ contact | contact_input: 'message'}}
      <label class="instruction">Please provide all the information you possibly can. </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="label">
      <label for="captcha">Spam Protection</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      {{ contact.captcha }}<br/>
      {{ contact | contact_input: 'captcha' }}
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="button" />
    </div><!-- end .submit -->
  </li>
</ul>
</form>
{% endif %}
</fieldset>​
```

Is it possible for me to add custom fields to this form? Or this dictated by underlying server logic?

Can you also explain, what do constructions with `id="field"` do? Where are field names?

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting form, and I've never seen forms done that way, but it looks to me like all of the fields in this page are formatted something like this:

```
<li>
  <div class = "foobar">
    // Label and Such
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    // Actual input
  </div>
</li>
```

It also looks like this is really relevant to your CSS, can we see what that looks like?

-Brian